# Is there any upgrade to Shampoodle?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've been getting my hair changed everyday just in case there is an upgrade available, but if there's not I don't really feel the need to change my hair every day.

Does Shampoodle every upgrade?  After what conditions?  Is there only one upgrade?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are essentially two upgrades. The store doesn't visibly upgrade at all.

You are given the choice to change your eye color after:

- Shampoodle has been around for two weeks
- You have gotten at least one haircut or Mii Mask change.

[This can be found here](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Shampoodle).

And you can get the hair styles of the opposite sex after:

- Getting one of every hair style of your sex.
- (This is also a 2 week requirement since you can only get one per day and there are 15 styles each.)

[Both of the upgrade requirements can be found here as well.](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/post/50410132084/animal-crossing-new-leaf-shampoodle)

Comment: "After two weeks".  Does this mean after two weeks of getting a haircut everyday?  Or just two full weeks no matter what?

Comment: You need to get a haircut at least once. But that's it.

Comment: There is also the ability to get haircuts of the opposite gender after you get enough (Fifteen?  All the styles? Reports seem to vary.) stylings.

Comment: I removed my accepted answer vote.  I thought this was true, but my wife just told me she is now able to get "boy's hair styles" at Shampoodle now.  Is this a second "upgrade" after the eye color?  She visits the salon often, so I am not sure what the requirements are to get this...

Comment: I just saw the comment above this by @Margaret.  Thanks, I hope someone answers with a more clear answer!

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Reafexus updated the answer, that covers everything, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

My store did actually visually upgrade, (she got a new red machine, instead of the old white one, and she has seats now and an extra shelf) the outside hasn't changed but the inside has